# Module Federation Plugin and Responsive layout

Tags: responsive, breakpoints, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I'm start using Micro Frontend with Module Federation Plugin . Now i faced with some issues. One of my remote App have a Responsive layout. I implement breackpoints from MUI. When app works in isolation - everything works. But in a Host App it doesn't change at all. So any recommendation how i can figure up with it?

Answer (score 0):

So i understand that you have 2 apps, one provides a responsive component (remote) and the other consumes(host) it, right? Now, first thing:

- if you've implemented breakpoints in the remote app's App.js, it's obviously not going to effect anything on the host app.

Secondly- if "implementing breakpoints" means using a `<ThemeProvider/>` then you also going to have troubles theming remote components on the 'host' app.
You'll need to add a field to the "shared" object in the ModuleFederationPlugin:

```
'@emotion/react': {
     singleton: true,
     requiredVersion: deps['@emotion/react'],
},
```

This field is crucial in order to succesfully theme remote components. Challenges like these are very common when using ModuleFederation because of the inherit complexity of the use-cases it deals with and they are also somewhat hard to debug